# Free, private repositories where I can store and manage project files?

Tags: webapp-rec

Are there any good free repositories where I can store and manage my project's files?

I know of some, but I've heard that anyone can edit your files.

Do you know of any good repository which is free and *where only we have the right to edit or make any changes to the stored files?*

Please mention the pros and cons of ones you suggest, and also if possible, explain the procedure of usage of that repository.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/plans) offers a free plan that allows you to have unlimited private and public repositories shared between 5 users maximum. You would need to use [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or Subversion to manage the files though, but if you're familiar with source control tools it should be easy enough.

**Pros**

- Unlimited space and repositories
- Integrates with other services (ex: with Basecamp)
- Comes with its own Wiki
- Now owned by Atlassian (there should be some features to integrate the service with Jira and Confluence some day)

**Cons**

- You need to use Git, Mercurial or Subversion to access it (you could read the files with a browser, but to add and edit you would need one of those tools).

Comment: if he is not used to SCM I think  he will not bother to learn how to use it

Comment: FYI Bitbucket just changed their policies to be much more generous.  You can now create unlimited public and private repositories of unlimited size.  The only limit know is the number of private users you can assign to your repo.  The free limit is currently 5 users.

Comment: et al - it is not a "Con" to use Mercurial. They are both great, and Mercurial was the whole point of creating BitBucket.

Comment: @orokusaki - It's a "con" for non-tech savvy users.

Comment: so is programming.

Comment: Bitbucket now supports Git.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using [ProjectLocker](https://www.projectlocker.com/).  Mainly cause it was super easy to use!  They provide Source Control, Automated Builds, Trac, Wikis.

Answer (score 3):

[Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/home) also offers [free SVN or Git repository hosting](http://offers.assembla.com/free/).

Their free plans have unlimited users/repos (public or private) with 2GB total disk space.

Answer (score 1):

I have a free SVN account on a site called [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/). Works great with both Eclipse and Visual Studio. They also provide GIT and Trac support. While their free plan is good enough for me, most of their [plans](http://unfuddle.com/about/tour/plans) look quite affordable if you have a team.

Answer (score 1):

I am using **[Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/)** - they have a free plan and I like it.

Some features included in all versions:

> Private Repositories - By default both Git and Subversion repositories are private.
>   SSL Encryption
>
> Enables 128-bit SSL encryption over HTTP (HTTPS) for more secure checkouts and commits.
>   Daily Backups
>
> Daily backups of all customer data.

Answer (score 1):

[GitHub](https://github.com/) tends to be the most popular as of now, its only drawback being that any free project has to be open source.

Comment: GitHub is awesome, but that drawback is a huge one for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are used to [VCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)es there are plenty choices, like the one GoodEnough pointed. But to a broader public there are the online backup and sharing web apps like [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com/)

Answer (score 0):

### [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/)

> #### About the CodePlex Site
>
> CodePlex is Microsoft's open source project
> hosting web site. You can use CodePlex
> to create new projects to share with
> the world, join others who have
> already started their own projects, or
> use the applications on this site and
> provide feedback.provide feedback.
>
> #### CodePlex Features
>
> CodePlex includes the following features:
>
> - Source Code Control
> - Project
> - Discussions
> - Wiki Pages
> - Feature / Issue Tracking
> - Release Downloads
> - News Feed Aggregation

Fore more information .... About [CodePlex](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=About%20the%20CodePlex%20Site)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Unfuddle](http://Unfuddle.com) since almost 2 years. Good, reliable and free. I recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using http://www.xp-dev.com. It is very nice and integrates with a lot of other online systems such as basecamp and Fogbuzz among others. It only offers subversion hosting on the free plan though.